# How to compare time in if condition?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
tag=$(awk -F, 'NR==1{print $1}' /tmp/time.txt)# output: 17:00
sub_time=$(date -d"${tag}  +1:00" +'%H:%M')output: 16:00
current_time=$(date |awk 'NR==1{print $4}' output: 05:51:16
if [[ "$sub_time" -ge "$current_time" ]];then
   crontab  <<EOF
   */15 * * * *  bash server_shutdown.sh
EOF
fi
```

> I want to compare the "current_time" in the current system to the VM shutdown tag from VM with  "sub_time" through the if condition.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  What is subtime? Why 17:00+1 = 16:00? Why do you use `awk` to filter output of `date` instead of using `date`s format string? What does not work (any errors)? Obviously `-ge` can only compare integers ... but you should still add this to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be safer to convert the `date` strings to timestamps:

> `%s`     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC

```bsh
[[ $(date +%s -d "$sub_time") -ge $(date +%s -d "$current_time") ]]
```

---

Of course you could directly do this when creating the variables:

```bsh
sub_time=$(date -d"${tag}  +1:00" +%s)
current_time=$(date +%s)
if [[ $subtime -ge $current_time ]]; then
   ...
fi
```

---

- Instead of creating `current_time` by yourself, you could use the bash variable `$EPOCHSECONDS` (`bash` > 5.0).
- You could also use `printf` instead of `date` to create it: `printf -v current_time '%(%s)T'`

Be aware that these options might not be very portable.

Comment: azureuser@puppetclient-ubuntu:~$ echo $current_time
"1632388663"
azureuser@puppetclient-ubuntu:~$ echo $sub_time
1632384000
else condition is getting executed why.?

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
tag=$(awk -F, 'NR==1{print $1}' /tmp/time.txt)# output: 17:00
sub_time=$(date -d"${tag}  +1:00" +'%H:%M')#output: 16:00
current_time=$(date |awk 'NR==1{print substr($5,0,5)}')#output: 05:51
# on my system the 5th field has the time while the 4th field has the year.
# so I changed that in awk
if [[ "$sub_time" > "$current_time" ]];then # comparison done lexicographically
   crontab  <<EOF
   */15 * * * *  bash server_shutdown.sh
EOF
fi
```

Comment: Instead of filtering `date` output with  `awk`, why not simply use `date +%H:%M` ?

Comment: after if condition get satisfied also my cron job is not created why?

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.PLumo & Mahek the  both the answers works for me .